# need a mini edge connector for my pcb

Tags: pcb, connector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best edge connector for my pcb?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37989/best-edge-connector-for-my-pcb)

I want to find a mini jtag connector (about 1.00mm pitch, 6~10 positions) to connect to the edge of my pcb.
Something like these but with opening on the side so the PCB does not need to extend:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/91930-21109LF/609-1588-ND/1001902

or

[image: JTAG Connector]

I spent lots of time searching, but still cannot find anything suitable.
All suggestions for how to solve the problem are appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using the small 1mm contact spacing connectors on my board. I then use a Parlex type 1mm type flex cable to connect to the normal programming pod cable. See the example here:
http://www.carousel-design.com/SiLabs_ICD.html