# Low cost connector for two stacked PCBs

Tags: pcb, connector, board

I know we should not ask for product advice here, but I searched a lot for a specific board connection solution lately and it almost drives me crazy that I have only found so little options.

I need to connect two PCB spaced/stacked 26-28mm apart with at least 50 pins carrying each max. 1A current at lowest possible cost. Both boards can only be assembled on TOP side (Because both boards are on the same panel.) SMT and THT is ok, but no press fit. I need to be able to disconnect the boards. Special requirement: I can not turn one board head over heels because of other connectors that must remain the same orientation. So I need something like a header for the lower board and a **reverse** mount socket for the upper board.

Single row connectors would be ok.

First I thought about standard ribbon cable, but this seems to be way more expensive than other solutions. Then I thought about standard FFC/PFC cable. The standard 0.5mm pitch types are cheap, but I would need way more than 50 pins to distribute the >1A current of some of the power lines, which makes it expensive.

Then the Samtec [BSW-125-04-T-D](http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/bsw.pdf) and [TSW-125-18-F-D](http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/tsw_th.pdf) came to my attention. This is a standard 2-row 2.54mm SMT header (TSW) combined with a reverse entry SMT socket (BSW.) Together, this solution costs about 5.50 USD at 1kpcs median at octopart.

So my question is: Can anyone name a "type" of connection or even a product that could beat the 5.50 USD mark from above? Maybe you have met other connection systems that I haven't thought of.

Comment: What kind of quantities?

Comment: 3k pcs per year

Comment: An inch spacing doesn't leave you with many options. I would have suggested the LSHM since it's snaps together easier (I find long dual rows of square post header B2B to be a pain to connect and disconnect), is polarized, cheaper, and hermaphroditic so you only need one part. But it is only 12mm maximum stacking height.

Comment: What is the size of your board stack?  Will single-row pins work for you?  Do you have to be able to take the stack apart or can both boards be soldered directly to the pins?

Comment: I need to be able to take the stack apart. I have only to PCB boards to connect.

Comment: @DKNguyen The LSHM does not fit the specs because i would have to assemble one of them on the other side of the board. I have one panel where I can only assemble TOP and I can not turn one board head over heels. (see updated question).

Comment: @StefanWyss I don't understand what you mean because after depanelizing the boards can be flipped however you want to be connected together

Comment: @DKNguyen After depanelizing the boards, I can not flip one board because of multiple fitted connectors on both boards that must remain the same orientation, i.e. all connectors must face from PCB board to the sky

Comment: What about the old PC/104 board format?  Here's a link to another SE thread on that topic: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42530/ideas-to-stack-multiple-pcbs-on-top-of-each-other

Answer (score 1):

[DW-50-14-T-S-1100](http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/dw.pdf) are US$3.20 at quantity 1 from Digikey. I have used them before (with fewer pins) and they do the trick.

[image: Samtec DW]

I have also used card-edge connectors [like these](https://www.stocko-contact.com/en/products-connector-system-pitch-2.5-mm-eco-tronic.php).  It'll probably be more pricey since you'll have to assemble the harnesses but it may still come under your price point.

[image: Stock edge connectors]

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the socket for the DW solution? (I need a disconnectable solution)

Comment: @StefanWyss The manufacturer on the datasheet calcium3000 linked to leads to [www.samtec.com/connectors/standard-board-to-board](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/standard-board-to-board).

Comment: @StefanWyss also any generic 01x50, 2.54 mm-pitch female headers will do, especially if your board height is flexible.

Comment: Thanks all of you for comments. I think I did not express the problem clearly enough. I need a header and a reverse mount socket. (See question update above).