Best way to stack 2 PCBs flush to one another with connectors
I am looking for a way to stack 2 PCBs on top of each other, with the top PCB flush with the bottom one (similar to castellated modules). However, I am looking for a solution that can be easily disconnected and can be automatically assembled by an inexpensive fab house. The PCBs also need to be somewhat precisely aligned.
I had a look at mill-max press fit pins and samtec bottom insertion sockets with alignement pegs, which could be useful for the bottom PCB (female) but not sure how to connect the top PCB (male)
Edit: some more details
The connector is for low-speed protocols (e.g. 10MBps SPI). Ideally should support at least a hundred mating cycles. Mating height on the other side is less important

On top and bottom of your PCB sandwich, how much build height can you accept?

The choice of connector depends on mated height, number of pins, how often it should be removed, requirements regarding ruggedness, RF and speed concerns etc etc. Your specification is too vague to pick any particular connector technology.

Mezzanine connectors is the standard solution: they are cheap:ish, small and compact but not rugged. They are meant to get attached ones and maybe just removed once or twice throughout the product's life time, perfect for consumer electronics. For more rugged connectors something like 2mm "bottom entry" socket/header strips is cheap & reliable and can handle lots of matings. But they take more board space since need to drill holes through one of the boards.

Look at what they did with PC-104 modules, which is  one of the solutions suggested here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42530/ideas-to-stack-multiple-pcbs-on-top-of-each-other

@Lundin, Sorry for the lack of details, I've updated the question

You say: "Mating height on the other side is less important". What do you mean by "the other side"? The top side (above the daughterboard)? Or the bottom side (under the motherboard)?

Sorry I was not clear, I mean the top side on the MB

What is the purpose to have zero space between the boards? Especially when the height of the total stack is unimportant. Could the OP just mount one board on the other and have a flat flexible cable joing the two? A hole and a slot (with pins), a Kelvin or Maxwell clamp to provide correct alignment between the boards. What make the relative locations inportant and not the relationship between the chassis and the top board?

Can you put a real spec on what you mean by "flush"?  Is 1mm good?  5mm?

Are these surface mount or through hole boards?  If SMT, then can the two boards be mounter back to back?

Your requirement that the boards be flush against one-another (zero mating height) cannot be met with standard board-to-board connectors because all board-to-board connectors are sandwiched between the two boards and space the two boards apart. Even dual-beam connectors (the flattest mezzanine connectors) raise the the daughterboard at least 0.5 mm off the motherboard. Single-piece interposers between the boards also have a non-zero thickness.
To stack the boards with 0 mm spacing you need through-board connectors with no housing between the boards. Any housing would need to be above the daughterboard or below the motherboard.
Here are some options using shroudless strips:
Through-hole pins on the motherboard and an SMT bottom-entry shroudless female strip on the daughterboard.

A shroudless male header mounted on the bottom of the motherboard and an SMT bottom-entry shroudless female strip on the daughterboard.

Here is a solution using loose PCB terminals. There's nothing below the motherboard and just the protruding pins above the daughterboard. Mill-max makes bottom-entry sockets: 8874


That's the solution I was considering (bottom entry sockets). In your example, how are the male headers attached? Are they press-fit?

"how are the male headers attached?". They are soldered to the plated-through holes. Press-fit won't work because the press-fit end in on the bottom side of the plastic wafer, and that side is not inside the PCB holes.

I see so they are soldered on the top side, I guess the holes for the bottom entry connectors need to account for the solder joints

In the top and the bottom solutions, the pins are soldered from the bottom: no solder on the top of the board.

I like the last solution with the loose socket terminals and pins. Do you have any manufacturer recommendation? I know about mill-max but they seem to only offer press-fit options for their flush versions, and a soldered version with a small lip

"Do you have any manufacturer recommendation?" for which, the socket or the pin? I edited my answer and added a MillMax part.

A little detail here: one should consider PCB thickness. If the current requirements are made assuming standard 1.6mm PCB, we can perhaps switch to 0.8mm and then we have suddenly freed 0.8mm stacking height. Which could perhaps be used for SMD mounting the socket strip on the motherboard. Or switching to some mezzanine flavour. (100 mating cycles as per OP's edit might rule out mezzanine completely though?)

With 0.8mm of space, I would be concerned about how to maintain mechanical stability between the boards, at the end furthest from the connector. Zero is much easier on that front. Depending on the size and weight of the daughterboard I guess, if it's tiny it might be fine

@DavideAndrea, looking at the Mill-Max sockets you linked, it looks like the sockets are not really bottom-entry; the bottom entry configuration is just the same as the top entry, but with the sockets soldered backwards
https://www.mill-max.com/sites/default/files/external/assets/2021-05/8874_receptacle.pdf
This is fine, but takes some additional room

"the sockets are not really bottom-entry". I disagree. Figure 2 shows how they work as bottom entry. Note that the collet is 0.062 inches tall, the same height as the thickness of a standard PCB. Therefore, they do not protrude from the bottom surface of the PCB. That sheet says: "Used in this
manner, the entry end of the receptacle will not protrude
through boards that are greater than .024” thick, thereby
allowing the plugged-in component/device to have as low
a profile as possible while remaining removeable & replace-
able without soldering."

Aren't there risks involved with mechanical stresses during (repeated) insertions which are not quite in the usual direction (pushing from the bottom, away from the solder, rather than from the top, towards the solder)?

@jcaron: If you're asking about the loose sockets: or loose pins a) these sockets are designed for bottom insertion. b) most of the retention is from the solder inside the plated-through hole, not from the solder on the top or bottom side.

@jcaron: If you're asking about the SMT bottom entry female strip: I think your point is valid.

@DavideAndrea Yes, I was thinking more about the bottom entry female strip, but good to know about those loose sockets, I wasn't familiar at all with those.

@jcaron: You got me thinking: just as bottom-entry SMT headers are stressed during mating, top-entry SMT headers are equally stressed during unmating. Therefore, SMT headers are equally stressed whether top or bottom entry. Right?

@DavideAndrea I wondered about it. For some reason I have the feeling that the insertion stress must be higher than the unmating one, though I honestly cannot give any decent explanation for that. Possibly the fact that there are chances of slight misalignments during insertion, and the fact that insertion must cause the connector to move out, and not just the friction, which should require a little bit more force?

We have been using the second option with 1.75mm headers for a while now and it should be noted that they are usually not absolutely flush as there is a tiny bit of solder flowing through leaving a teeny tiny gap

Search for mezzanine connectors or board to board connectors

OP wants the boards to be flush. Mezzanine connectors space the boards apart at least 0.8 mm.

Take a look at the following product portfolio from Molex:
https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/connectors/board-to-board-connectors/c-grid
I suggest this product line:
https://www.molex.com/en-us/part-list/0039?general_componentType=PCB%20Receptacle
In terms of costs and variety of products, Molex performs much better with respect to the 2 manufacturers you mentioned.

Could you be more specific in your recommendation please? Linked page has a lot of different stuff ..
