# Help identifying 1.27mm spring-loaded connector

Tags: connector, identification

I'm planning building a small board that will interface with a connector pad that has pins with 1.27mm spacing between them. It has 26 pins in total but only about 5 are actually required.

I'm looking for a connector that is basically [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37989/best-edge-connector-for-my-pcb/37996#37996) but for a pitch of 1.27mm.

[image]

I looked everywhere online but could not find such connector. The only one I could find was [this connector on Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/70ABJ-4-M0E/70ABJ-4-M0ECT-ND/2037596) but it only has 4 pins.

Does anyone know where I could get such a connector (at an affordable price)? This is for a small project so I'll only need about 15 at most.

Comment: What are you interfacing? A link would be useful.

Comment: It's a proprietary connector that looks something like this: http://i50.tinypic.com/35cqt0p.jpg

Comment: Could someone explain why the downvote? I don't believe this was an unreasonable question.

Comment: Isn't that an edge connector? It looks quite similar to PCI, which has the 1.27mm pitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.digikey.com.au/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?vendor=0&keywords=samtec+sib

In the question you referenced, there is a link to a datasheet with a part name - santec SIB series. You could put multiple units side-by-side to give more pins.

Edit:

How about these:

http://www.samtec.com/technical-specifications/default.aspx?SeriesMaster=SIBF

Comment: Unfortunately the ones you linked have a 2.54mm pitch and not 1.27mm. The 1.27mm ones I found won't work when placed side by side together because of the width of the sides.

Comment: Jsut put a link to the SIBF with 0.05" pitch, can't find a supplier with them in stock.

Comment: These look like the ones I need. I'll have a hunt around for stock. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Samtec -  Create a free account and you can request samples very quickly, or buy larger volumes. 
The SIBF and SEI connectors are mating connectors, i.e. you need one on each side. 
Your tinypic shows a board edge style, you could use a PCI-E or the MECF from samtec.