# What exact header is this?

Tags: identification, xbee, header, pin-headers

What type of headers are used by digi-international in the Development Kit of modules xbee 868lp. Are they commercial or are they developed by Digi?

[Digi XBee® SX 868](https://www.digi.com/products/embedded-systems/rf-modules/sub-1-ghz-modules/digi-xbee-sx-868)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks and best regards,
Fran Martin.

Comment: Can you also add a picture from the bottom side please?

Comment: Looks like it might be for attaching a pcb with castellated holes on the edges

Comment: They are [SPRING SKT XBEE SMD 10 13P 5 8P](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=76002056).

Comment: @AndrewMorton this should be an answer not a comment

Comment: @DanielK I do not know if they are commercial or developed by Digi.

Comment: your link lists digi as manufacturer, unfortunately none available and obsolete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castellation metal loop connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191176/castellation-metal-loop-connector)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think they are developed by digi.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen - I was sure I'd seen them in a question here *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve Andrew Morton's find if the comments get removed:

[SPRING SKT XBEE SMD 10 13P 5 8P](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/digi/76002056/3481914?s=N4IgTCBcDaIOwDYAMSxIKwJAXQL5A)

And finally [a link Jasen found to a possible duplicate question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191176/castellation-metal-loop-connector)

The parts in question appear to be difficult to source.