# What is the name of these connectors? (XBee Radio Module)

Tags: pcb, connector, surface-mount, xbee, edge-connector

I'm migrating a design from an older through hole module, to a new module that has edge connectors. The dev kit has these nice spring loaded connectors on the carrier board where the module just pops in, but I don't know what they're called. I've googled everything I can think of with no luck.

[image: Spring Edge Connectors]
[image: Radio Module]

Comment: this has been asked before ... i remember the picture of the spring contacts

Comment: The edges of the PCB are "castellated."  The spring contacts are new to me though.

Answer (score 0):

Asked before: [What exact header is this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450241/what-exact-header-is-this) (and others)

So as mentioned in the linked post it is these:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/digi/76002056/3481914?s=N4IgTCBcDaIOwDYAMSxIKwJAXQL5A

It appears to be obsolete though. I get some strange hits via octopart on the partnumber 76002056. It directs to the devboard and not the socket. (sortof; is that price correct?)

It seems to me that these are something properitary to digi. I would reach out directly to them. I have no idea, but they might sell them directly to you. Worth a try anyway.